# Cover Photo and Theme on Apple App Store

Tags: app-store

I noticed that a few applications like Candy Crush, Paper, Star Wars:Uprising have a theme and a cover photo on the App Store. 
I tried looking on Apple's guidelines but couldn't find anything related to it.

Does anyone know how it is done or if someone could direct me to where I can find the guidelines for using a theme or cover photo, that would be great!

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you found out yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! Please let me know if you find something. I think the cover and theme is added only by Apple for some special apps.

Comment: Have any of you found out yet? 

Comment: I think Apple selects the popular apps and allows them to add the Cover Photo and Themes. It isn't upto the developers unfortunately

Comment: hello, have found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Only featured apps can have cover image or theme for customization. These applications are selected by Apple based on popularity, media coverage, proper implementation of WWDC rules, Good UI/U experience. This isn't on the developer's hand to change cover image or theme.

Official confirmation about this is found on this site -

> Applications that have custom background art on the App Store are
>   selected editorially by Apple. If your application is selected to be
>   receive custom art, you will be contacted by an Apple representative.